# Connect to a webSocket and maintain a connection

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a connection to a websocket however, I am trying to maintain this connection as well and send/receive data to it, I have made a IRC like bot using

```
 s = socket.socket()
 s.connect((server,port))
 # etc, s.send/s.recv
```

Question is how do I do this with a web-socket? the same way I'm confused I have wiresharked the data and It has a get line rather than a command being sent to connection, so how would I maintain a connection to a WebSocket socket to send and receive the data. Links,example code,or anything really would be useful I just want a good start off to this project.

Also I am using python 3

Comment: can you use an already-made websocket client?

Comment: I do not believe so however maybe I can possibly build off of it or change it to do IRC bot like things?